# How do I propose artwork for this site, once it gets gradu-mated?

Tags: discussion, design

So, I really want to suggest that we incoroprate P52 - the oldest extant fragment of the New Testament we have:

[image]

It would convey the "People of the Book" and the scholarly thing we're going for.

So, how would I suggest it?

Comment: I think you just did :)

Comment: Some of us have been spit-balling ideas in [the Upper Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room).  Maybe we can use answers to this question to make more detailed (and impassioned) proposals?

Comment: Also, don't steal my ideas for Biblical Hermeneutics designs!  ;-)

Comment: Mr. Jin's been in the upper'oom, but his name doesn't auto fill on chat window so I don't know if he gets pinged (don't know if he wants to be pinged either)

Comment: This is he best place I can think of. I think I would reserve one post per major idea instead of everybody dogpiling on answers, but having major ideas tagged here on meta is the best way I know of. And I like your idea.

Comment: I would go for clean, professional and avoid complex religious icons.  Scroll fragments and Jons ancient symbol still speaks academic so not bad.  To much funky art has the danger of saying 'Church lady with a lunch bag'.

Answer (score 6):

So, I'm a huge fan of the mosaics in Ravenna (Italy), because they really are associated with Patristic Christianity in my mind.  They are *the* classical art form of the fledgling Christian community, and a mosiac feel for our header would cause me great joy...

[image: Good Shepherd Mosaic - From Mausoleo di Galla Placidia in Ravenna]

Mosaics also have the added advantage of making what I believe to be the perfect theological point this site is trying to make.  The church may be massively fragmented - but take just one step back, and it is a beautiful thing.  Individually, every piece plays its part - even the cracks and fissures that divide - into weaving the tapestry that is God's plan.  God uses the broken pieces of his church and our lives to make a masterpiece - which is exactly what a mosaic is.

Comment: You can chuck edit that if you want, I just wanted to put in a visual cue for how awesome your idea is.

Comment: @Peter you just really want to see sheep don't you? ;-)

Comment: I like the sheep :)  I'm glad Jesus chose sheep instead of cats :)

Comment: In all serious (a) I love that mosaic - I have that star hanging in my bedroom (the yellow circle with the bluish points) and (b) I think the mosaic really gets to the heart of what Christianity.Stack Exchange is - see my edits...  (Between Peter & me, I want to make this top of mind!!!)

Comment: I like the idea of [a mosaic](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6184531#6184531) design as well.  This example has the advantage of being colorful and complex.

Comment: This is the first idea that I like.

Answer (score 5):

This is my current favorite symbol to represent Christianity:

[image: Chi-Rho, Alpha-Omega wheel]

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_Rho):

> The Chi Rho is one of the earliest forms of christogram, and is used by Christians. It is formed by superimposing the first two (capital) letters chi and rho (ΧΡ) of the Greek word "ΧΡΙΣΤΟΣ" =Christ in such a way to produce the monogram. Although not technically a Christian cross, the Chi-Rho invokes the crucifixion of Jesus, as well as symbolizing his status as the Christ.

It also contains an even earlier symbol from "I am the Alpha and the Omega, the first and the last, the beginning and the end." (Revelation 22:13 [ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/Revelation+22/))  It is also a [common symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_and_Omega) found in both the Greek and Latin traditions.

I also like the circle around the whole thing.  I'm not sure if it's a particularly Christian thing, but I like that it looks like a wheel.

If we are going to use standard Christian symbols, we should probably have as much going on as possible to represent the mosaic of people and traditions our site represents.

Comment: That's the Celtic Cross

Answer (score 4):

I say sheep:

[image]

It's a good animal because it represents

1. One in need of help.
2. A member of a larger community.
3. A symbol used by both Johns for Christ
4. Is more NTish than OTish and more C.SE than BH.SE.

Comment: Would you add a lot of goats and a few wolves as an indication of what who's hanging out here?